# Arch ISO build error

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, build

I was making a custom Arch buid. While building the live DE an error came up. I used the command:

```
sudo ./build.sh -v
```

At first it downloaded some packages and then gave me an error. I cannot read the error completely because it is so long. Here is one part:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please translate the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured how to complete the command withouth an error. Just maked the language English

Comment: I selected that reason, because your solution, is not specific enough.  While switching the language to English might have been the solution you don't explain the steps to do that.